# How to create a substraste chain?

Tags: yarnpkg, rust-cargo, substrate, polkadot

I need HELP

I have two major errors in creating my first substraste chain (cf. https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/create-your-first-substrate-chain/setup)

**Error in Installing the Front-End Template**

> ~/Bureau/ETH-BIT/substrate/substrate-front-end-template$ ls LICENSE
> package.json public README.md src yarn.lock
> pclf@ubuntu:~/Bureau/ETH-BIT/substrate/substrate-front-end-template$
> ***yarn install***
> ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'install'

**Error in compiling Substrate**

> ***cargo build --release***
> error: failed to run custom build command for `node-template-runtime v2.0.0 (/home/pclf/Bureau/ETH-BIT/substrate/substrate-node-template/runtime)`
>
> Caused by:   process didn't exit successfully:
> `/home/pclf/Bureau/ETH-BIT/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/node-template-runtime-663c8dc25926c960/build-script-build`
> (exit code: 1)   --- stdout   Executing build command: "rustup" "run"
> "nightly" "cargo" "rustc" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown"
> "--manifest-path=/home/pclf/Bureau/ETH-BIT/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/Cargo.toml" "--color=always" "--release"
>
> --- stderr
> Compiling wasm-build-runner-impl v1.0.0 (/home/pclf/Bureau/ETH-BIT/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild-runner/node-template-runtime4021631938540302808)
> Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 7.49s
> Running `/home/pclf/Bureau/ETH-BIT/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild-runner/node-template-runtime4021631938540302808/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/wasm-build-runner-impl`
> Compiling sp-arithmetic v2.0.0
> Compiling sp-io v2.0.0
> Compiling sp-inherents v2.0.0
> Compiling frame-metadata v12.0.0
> Compiling sp-finality-tracker v2.0.0   error[E0282]: type annotations needed
> --> /home/pclf/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/sp-arithmetic-2.0.0/src/fixed_point.rs:541:9
> |   541  |                   let accuracy = P::ACCURACY.saturated_into();
> |                       ^^^^^^^^ consider giving `accuracy` a type   ...   1595 | / implement_fixed!(   1596 | |     FixedI64,
> 1597 | |     test_fixed_i64,   1598 | |     i64,   ...    |   1601 | |
> "*Fixed Point 64 bits signed, range = [-9223372036.854775808,
> 9223372036.854775807]*",   1602 | | );
> | |__- in this macro invocation
> |
> = note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
>
> error[E0282]: type annotations needed
> --> /home/pclf/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/sp-arithmetic-2.0.0/src/fixed_point.rs:541:9
> |   541  |                   let accuracy = P::ACCURACY.saturated_into();
> |                       ^^^^^^^^ consider giving `accuracy` a type   ...   1604 | / implement_fixed!(   1605 | |     FixedI128,
> 1606 | |     test_fixed_i128,   1607 | |     i128,   ...    |   1611 |
> |         [-170141183460469231731.687303715884105728,
> 170141183460469231731.687303715884105727]_",   1612 | | );
> | |__- in this macro invocation
> |
> = note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
>
> error[E0282]: type annotations needed
> --> /home/pclf/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/sp-arithmetic-2.0.0/src/fixed_point.rs:541:9
> |   541  |                   let accuracy = P::ACCURACY.saturated_into();
> |                       ^^^^^^^^ consider giving `accuracy` a type   ...   1614 | / implement_fixed!(   1615 | |     FixedU128,
> 1616 | |     test_fixed_u128,   1617 | |     u128,   ...    |   1621 |
> |         [0.000000000000000000,
> 340282366920938463463.374607431768211455]_",   1622 | | );
> | |__- in this macro invocation
> |
> = note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
>
> error: aborting due to 3 previous errors
>
> For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0282`.
> error: could not compile `sp-arithmetic`
>
> error: build failed

Answer (score 2):

You can just run `yarn` in the front end template directory, it will work. But where is the "Is LICENCE public" message coming from? You shouldn't see that. Did you clone the substrate-front-end-template repo or just create the directory? The exact process is:

- clone it with `git clone https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-front-end-template`
- enter folder with `cd substrate-front-end-template`
- run `yarn`

As for the Substrate compilation error, please downgrade your nightly to an older version, it happens due to a [bug in Rust](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/77653). Here is how to do that:

```sh
rustup uninstall nightly
rustup install nightly-2020-10-01
rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain nightly-2020-10-01
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing first solve the Substrate compiling first.
run this scrip

```
https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/master/scripts/init.sh
```

When you get the node up and running then start using frontend.